# how to calculate matrix in excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have a spread sheet of (36x1) with matrix (1x15). I want to calculate a matrix value. I use Microsoft Excel 2016. My coding is =MMULT(A1:Z1 B5:19). The answer is you input too view arguments of this function. I think I have made a wrong calculation. But it clear I follow from the website or other person who can calculate the matrix.  Is there any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

Select the output range. Input the formula:

```
=MMULT(A1:Z1;B5:19)
```

Then press the keys `[Ctrl] + [Shift] + [Enter]`

Answer (score 0):

I follow your suggestion and the answer is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tygcl.png). I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you enter the wrong format of MMULT() formula. The right format is "=MMULT(array1, array2)". Maybe you should input the formula:

```
=MMULT(A1:Z1,B5:B19)
```

Please refer to [MMULT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mmult-function-40593ed7-a3cd-4b6b-b9a3-e4ad3c7245eb) and [Create an array formula that calculates a multiple result](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d).

Note that you need to select multiple cells and press `[Ctrl] + [Shift] + [Enter]`. For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I send you again my figure. It seems not to difficult to formulate MMULT, but it still doesn't work. Cam yout tell me how to calculate in manual mannner? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSJfS.png)

Comment: In your formula, there should be a comma instead of a semicolon between the two parameters. If you want to get a multiple result, you need to select multiple cells and press {[Ctrl] + [Shift] + [Enter]}. Please refer to the links from my answer.